# why this error how me(building ROS Package)?

Tags: ros

**when i build my package in ROS this error show me, how can fix this?**
*i should fix this*

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
      execute_process(/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
      "/usr/bin/python3" "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py" "--raw-errors"
      "-F"
      "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/qrcode_detection/cmake/amrl_qrcode_detection-genmsg-context.py"
      "-o"
      "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/qrcode_detection/cmake/amrl_qrcode_detection-genmsg.cmake"
      "/opt/ros/noetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em") returned error
      code 1
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
      /opt/ros/noetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (em_expand)
      qrcode_detection/CMakeLists.txt:28 (generate_messages)
    

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Comment: More info is needed here. What does the CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: like this:  https://github.com/mrl-amrl/amrl-vision/blob/master/qrcode_detection/CMakeLists.txt